# Регулярка, которая ищет непрерывные последовательности

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В общем, есть такие данные:

Абрамова А.Л., Абрамов И.И., 1954-55, 1958

Wаng Wеi (1951) — LЕ

Мне нужно вычленять ФИО, инициалы могут идти в любом порядке и быть неполными.

Я нарисовал уже регулярку `[\p{L}.\s\-]+`, но уж больно много мусора она захватывает...

Например, в первом примере, вытягивает лишние пробелы и -, а во втором вытягивает LE. В первом случае, она должна возвращать 2 совпадения.
Как можно ее усилить?

Comment: `Wаng Wеi` в вашем примере имеют русские `а` и `е`

Comment: Косяк Fine Reader=(

Answer (score 2):

С учетом предоставленных в вопросе данных, можно попробовать с такой регуляркой (с флагом игнорирования регистра):

```regex
[а-яё]+\s+[а-яё]\.[а-яё]\.|[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q5WMHK/1/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Проверка на python:

```
import re

text = '''\
Абрамова А.Л., Абрамов И.И., 1954-55, 1958
Wang Wei (1951) — LЕ
'''

pattern = '[а-яё]+\s+[а-яё]\.[а-яё]\.|[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+'
print(re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Результат:

```
['Абрамова А.Л.', 'Абрамов И.И.', 'Wаng Wеi']
```

---

Выглядит некрасиво, но эта регулярка сможет найти и кириллицу, и латиницу: `Можно попробовать: [a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+\s+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]\.[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]\.|[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+\s+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ]+`